# Showing $\{\alpha^0, \alpha^2, \ldots , \alpha^{n-1}\}$ Serves as Basis for $F(\alpha)$ If $\alpha$ is Algebraic

Tags: galois-theory

1. Let $E$ be a field extension of $F$.
2. Let $\alpha \in E$ be algebraic over $F$.
3. Consider $F(\alpha)$ -- the field of all rational fractions of polynomials of $\alpha$.
4. We have by another theorem that $\exists p(x) \in F(x)$ s.t. $p(x)$ is monic, $p(\alpha) = 0$, and if $g(\alpha) = 0$ then $f(x)\,\,|\,\, g(x)$.  Fix $deg(p) = n$.

**Question:** Why is it true $\{\alpha^0, \alpha^2, \ldots , \alpha^{n-1}\}$ serves as a basis for $F(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The span of this set is at least the polynomials in $\alpha$ of degree at most $n-1$. (Q1) Why are polynomials of higher degree not considered? (Q2) If zero was a nontrivial linear combination, what could you say about the degree of $p$?

Comment: I'm still unclear on the spanning argument.  For linear independence, if $\{0, \ldots , \alpha^{n-1}\}$ weren't linearly independent, then some non-trivial linear combination of these elements would equal $0$ and be of degree less than $n$ -- the degree of minimal polynomial $f(x)$ -- hence a contradiction.

Comment: @user1770201: Exactly. For the spanning part, look at a more concrete example: $i\in\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$. Why is it enough to consider $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}(i)$ as the the degree-at-most-one polynomials in $i$?

Comment: Any $z = a + bi$ is a $1$-degree real polynomial of $i$.  And if one didn't know that, since $i^2 = -1 \in \mathbb{R}$, considering real polynomials of $i$ of degrees more than $1$ wouldn't get you any new elements of $\mathbb{C}$ anyway.  So in this case our basis would be $\{i^0, i^1\}$.

Comment: I think this is what you're getting at?  Suppose $m(\alpha) = f_1 + f_2 \alpha + \ldots + \alpha^n$ is our minimal polynomial.  Then $\alpha^n = -f_1 - f_2 \alpha - \ldots - f_n a^{n-1}$.  Then from here any linear combination involving powers of $\alpha$ of $n$ or greater can, through repeated substitution, be made into a linear combination of $\{1, \ldots , \alpha^n\}$ via the fact that we have expressed $\alpha^n$ as a linear combination of the members of $\{1, \ldots , \alpha^n\}$.

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb{C}$, we have that $1 + i^2$ is the minimal polynomial $\implies i^2 = -1$. Then if we considered, say, $i^5 + 5i + 9$ we would have $i^5 + 5i + 9 = i^2 i^2 i + 5i + 9 = (-1)(-1)i + 5i + 9$ as our linear combination of the elements from $\{1,i\}$.

Comment: @user1770201: Yup, that's great! If I were writing up the problem I would couch the "repeated substitution" recursion in the framework of the Euclidean algorithm, but you have all the important ideas.